# JS: Is there a difference between class.prototype.constructor and class.constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

In a tutorial I am reading, there is a part I don't understand:

```
function User (theName, theEmail) {
    this.name = theName;
    this.email = theEmail;
    this.quizScores = [];
    this.currentScore = 0;
}
​
User.prototype = {
    constructor: User,
    saveScore:function (theScoreToAdd)  {
        this.quizScores.push(theScoreToAdd)
    },
    showNameAndScores:function ()  {
        var scores = this.quizScores.length > 0 ? this.quizScores.join(",") : "No Scores Yet";
        return this.name + " Scores: " + scores;
    },
    changeEmail:function (newEmail)  {
        this.email = newEmail;
        return "New Email Saved: " + this.email;
    }
}
```

I have read the post and checked the web but I don't really understand, is there a difference between saying: User.constructor and User.prototype.constructor?
(Like on Line 9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `User.constructor` sets the constructor of the `User` instance. The `User.prototype.constructor` sets the constructor of *all instances*. Thus if you set

```
User.prototype.constructor = function test(){};
```

then

```
new User().constructor
```

will also be the `test` function.

Answer (score 1):

When you are doing

```
user.prototype={},
```

You are actually creating new object. So it will be

```
user.prototype=new Object()
```

and its constructor will change to Object, so to keep constructor to user object

```
 constructor: User
```

and constructor is property of prototype. To call constructor from class user, you need to create new instance of class user then only you can use constructor property directly